# Shutdown script not executing on Windows 7

Tags: vbscript, group-policy, windows-scripting

I opened `gpedit.msc` and went to:

```
Computer Configuration
  Windows Settings
    Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)
      Shutdown
```

and added a VBScript that I wrote. Extremely simple. All it does is create a text file with one line of text (deleting it if it already exists). I tested it by running it prior to setting this up and it works fine.  Takes about 1 second to run.

However, when I shutdown the computer (or restart it - either one), the text file does not appear to be created. Apparently the VBScript doesn't run? What am I doing wrong?